# MVC model + knockoutJS - glitchiness with rendering as bindings are applied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have the following approach for my MVC pages, responsible for applying bindings from the MVC `@Model`.  This is my `_Layout`, which currently uses `ViewBag` to gather data for the knockout `LayoutVm`:

```
<head>
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
</head>

// body contents, then at the bottom:

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@{
    var serialized = (string)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag);
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new LayoutVm(
                @Html.Raw(serialized.SanitizeData())), document.getElementById("nav-header")));
</script>
```

This is working, but it seems imperfect - I can see all of the knockout-bound elements render before any logic is applied, so initially the page looks a little messed up as elements that should be hidden are displayed, as if the viewmodel doesn't bind for a split second.  For example:

```
            <!-- ko if: isLoadingDropdown() -->
            <p class="dropdown-header">Loading...</p>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

`isLoadingDropdown` is initialized to false, but the inner content is displayed for a very short moment as the page renders.  What is the best way to address this?

Comment: Your `document.ready` is wrong.

Comment: @haim770 oh?  How so?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ko.applyBindings(new LayoutVm(
                @Html.Raw(serialized.SanitizeData())), document.getElementById("nav-header")) });`

Comment: @haim770 - I'm confused - how is wrapping it in a function better?

Comment: I don't think it'll solve the problem. but `document.ready` is expecting a `function`.

Comment: @haim770 It's working fine as is, minus the rendering glitch...

Comment: It's working fine, but it's not really running on `document.ready`.

Comment: @haim770 - I see.  Should I even be using `document.ready`?

Comment: Yes you should. `document.ready` means that the entire DOM is loaded into memory, and now it's time for Knockout to do it's magic (`applyBindings`). although i believe KO is doing the check as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide it until the binding is applied

http://jsfiddle.net/ehv83/

```
<body data-bind="visible: true" style="display: none">
    KO Content
</body>
```

Without inline css

http://jsfiddle.net/ehv83/1/